# MongoDB, issues with configuring and starting

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I am new to mongoDB and i am trying to get it configured and running on my Ubuntu server. When i go and enter this command in my terminal

```
sudo service mongod start
```

I get the following output

```
start: Job is already running: mongod
```

So, when i try to enter the shell with

```
mongo
```

I get the following output

```
2015-02-24T14:54:39.557-0800 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-02-24T14:54:39.559-0800 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
```

I know I'm not working locally so I heard over to the mongod.conf file and change the following

```
port = 5000

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
bind_ip = 10.0.1.51
```

Where bind_ip is now my ubuntu server and the port is 5000 as shown, so now i restart the service with

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

and outsputs

```
mongod start/running, process 1755
```

And now I try to renter back into shell with

```
mongo
```

and i still get the same error messages

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: test
2015-02-24T15:01:26.229-0800 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-02-24T15:01:26.230-0800 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

Can someone help me out with this issue? I've been going through the forums and nothing appears to be working. Thanks.

Comment: If you've changed the port and bind IP, you need to use the same options when starting the `mongo` shell, eg: `mongo 10.0.1.51:5000`. If you're allowing connections outside the localhost interface, it's also worth reading the [MongoDB Security Checklist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/) for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having trouble, i looked into `mongod --help` and found the following solutions

```
mongod --smallfiles
```

or

```
mongod --nojournal
```

hope this helps anyone.

Comment: it sounds like you're likely low on disk space where your `dbpath` is mounted, so `mongod` wasn't starting due to an error in the server logs that you haven't mentioned in your current question description :). A better approach would be to mount a volume with more space. FYI, running without journal is definitely not recommended if you care about your data. The smallfiles option also isn't a great approach if you're so low on disk space that `mongod` won't start without this.

Comment: why does mongod require so much disk space anyways? @Stennie

Comment: Disk space is preallocated to prevent file system fragmentation (see: [MongoDB Storage FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database)). FYI, the upcoming MongoDB 3.0 release supports multiple storage engines. The alternative [WiredTiger storage engine](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/release-notes/3.0/#wiredtiger) uses a different storage format which includes options for on-disk compression.